# Saving UIImage view into dictionary in SWIFT

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uiimageview, uiimage

Im working on an application that saves from the view controller (dictionary) to a table view  in the document directory, i added a button in the view controller that opens the UIImage and i also added a UIImage view. 
How can i save the images chosen, here is my code below, thank you for helping.

```
@IBAction func saveNote(sender: AnyObject) {
    if self.txtTitle.text.isEmpty {
        println("No title for was typed.")
        return
    }

    var noteDict = ["title": self.txtTitle.text, "body": self.tvBody.text]

    var dataArray: NSMutableArray

    if appDelegate.checkIfDataFileExists() {

        dataArray = NSMutableArray(contentsOfFile: appDelegate.getPathOfDataFile())


        dataArray.addObject(Dict)
    }
    else{

        dataArray = NSMutableArray(object: Dict)
    }


    dataArray.writeToFile(appDelegate.getPathOfDataFile(), atomically: true)

    self.navigationController!.popViewControllerAnimated(true)
}
```

Comment: You should not save imageView, instead save UIImage into dictionary.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are wanting to save the image rather than the image view itself. You can access the image property on your image view to get a reference to the image.

I would use UIImagePNGRepresentation() to convert the image to nsdata and then write that to  the file system, and save the url to the image data in your dictionary.

Reference for converting the image to data:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIKitFunctionReference/#//apple_ref/c/func/UIImagePNGRepresentation